# how compare value of datagridview cell is of decimal type or not

Tags: c#, datagridview

I made this code

```
(DataGridViewRow  dgRow in dgvMarksEntryForClass.Rows)
{
     if (dgRow.Cells["dgcolMarksObtain"].Value.GetType is decimal)
     {
         //some action
     }
     else { 
         //some action
     }
}
```

how do I check whether the value of

```
dgRow.Cells["dgcolMarksObtain"].Value.GetType
```

is of decimal type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the Decimal [TryParse()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.decimal.tryparse.aspx) method.

```
(DataGridViewRow  dgRow in dgvMarksEntryForClass.Rows)
{
    Decimal cellValue;
    if (Decimal.TryParse(dgRow.Cells["dgcolMarksObtain"].Value, out cellValue)
    {
         //some action
    }
    else
    {
        //some action
    }
}
```

Comment: can u please tell how to use tryparse()

Answer (score 0):

```
decimal value;
if(Decimal.TryParse(dgRow.Cells["dgcolMarksObtain"].Value.ToString(), out value))
  // It's a decimal
else
  // No it's not.
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this-

```
(DataGridViewRow  dgRow in dgvMarksEntryForClass.Rows)
{
     if (dgRow.Cells["dgcolMarksObtain"].Value.GetType() is decimal)
     {
         //some action
     }
     else { 
         //some action
     }
}
```

Comment: This will fail always